# XAMPP起動時にApache Service detected with wrong pathと表示される

Tags: apache, xampp

以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
8:05:47  [Apache]   Apache Service detected with wrong path
8:05:47  [Apache]   Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
8:05:47  [Apache]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
8:05:47  [Apache]   Found Path: "c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
8:05:47  [Apache]   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

前に一度apacheをインストールしましたが、Cドライブにコピペするだけという簡単なものでしたので、アンインストールするのも、そのフォルダを削除しましたが、エラーのFoundPathの項目で、削除できていないことになっているのですか？？以前のapacheの削除方法がわかりません。。。またほかに何か対策はありますか？？

---

**コメントより追記**

ご指摘の通り、変更したのですが、以下のようなエラーがでます。

```
21:56:58 [Apache] Found Path: "c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice 
21:56:58 [Apache] Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice 
21:56:58 [Apache] Problem detected! 21:56:58 [Apache] Port 80 in use by ""c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 6452!
21:56:58 [Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 
21:56:58 [Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 
21:56:58 [Apache] or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Answer (score 1):

前回にインストールされたApacheがサービスとして登録されたままになっているようです。

もしXAMPP Control Panel を管理者権限で起動した時にApacheのService列にチェックマークがついていれば、これをクリックし、現れたダイアログでYesを選択すると、サービスの登録を解除することができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

チェックマークがついていない場合は・・・

- 同じ場所に同じようにApacheをインストールし、管理者権限で起動したコマンドプロンプトから次のコマンドを実行する。

  ```
  cd /d c:\Apache24\bin  （注：インストール先\bin）
  httpd -k stop
  httpd -k uninstall
  ```
- あるいは、手動でサービスを停止・削除する

  1. ファイル名を指定して実行で `services.msc` を起動し、Apacheと名の付くサービスを探し、ダブルクリックでプロパティを開く
  2. [実行ファイルのパス]が前回インストールした場所と同じかどうか確認する
  3. [停止]が押せれば押す。サービス名（多分 Apache2.4）を覚えておく
  4. 管理者権限で起動したコマンドプロンプトで、 `sc delete サービス名` を実行する

> Problem detected! 21:56:58 [Apache] Port 80 in use by ""c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 6452!
>   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

XAMPP以外のApacheが既に起動しているようです。サービスとして起動されたもののようですから、上記のように `services.msc` で停止するのが簡単かと思います。
（もしくは再起動してしまうのも手ですが）

そのうえで正しいパスに修正するなり一度登録解除するなりしましょう。

Answer (score 0):

前にインストールしたものと競合してるんですよね？
例えば、XAMPPのほうのポートを変えるとか……
もう一度以前のApacheを入れてアンインストールをやりなおすとか

一応、同様の問題の記事があったので共有します。
ただ、レジストリを編集することになるので慎重にどうぞ

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> services -> 
>
>   Apache2.4 ->ImagePath` の値を`"c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice`に変更

http://vlpius.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/08/26/135929

---

リンク先の記事の方法を試したようですが、
リンク先と質問者さんとの環境の違いがあります。
エラー内容にも記載されておりますが、
質問者さんの環境だと`httpd`のパスが下記じゃないでしょうか？

×：`"c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice`に変更
○：`"c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice`に変更

また、unaristさんの回答もありますが、試してみて駄目だったようでしたら、
駄目だった旨もお知らせして頂けると質問者さんの状況が分かり解決がしやすくなります。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、変更したのですが、以下のようなエラーがでます。

Comment: @myaku21:56:58  
21:56:58  [Apache]  Found Path: "c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
21:56:58  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
21:56:58  [Apache]  Problem detected!
21:56:58  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by ""c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 6452!
21:56:58  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
21:56:58  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
21:56:58  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: @user7196197 追記いたしました。他の方への情報の共有や、見やすさのため、結果などの追加情報は質問文を編集し、編集追記した旨をコメントでお知らせください。

Answer (score 0):

原因は、Windowsのコントロールのプログラムと機能から、XAMPPをアンインストールしたのが原因の様です。
XAMPPを正規の方法でアンインストールしなおせば解消されると思われます。

C:\XAMPP\uninstall.exeがあります。このuninstall.exeを使用してアンインストールを実施して下さい。
実施し終わると、そのまま、Windowsが再起動されます。
Windowsが再起動後に、XAMPPを再度インストールして下さい。

XAMPPのApacheの起動に成功するはずです。