# XamppでMySQLが使用できない

Tags: mysql, xampp

・質問者情報
プログラミング関係を独学で学習し始めて約２か月の初心者です。
主に環境設定に苦戦しています。
基本的な知識の抜けも多いかもしれません、ご迷惑お掛けいたします。

以下のエラーを解消し、MySQLを使える状況にしたいのですが、何かいい方法ありますでしょうか？

> 13:58:20  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
>   13:58:20  [mysql]   Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
>   13:58:20  [mysql]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   13:58:20  [mysql]   Found Path: C:\xampp1\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp1\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
>   13:58:20  [mysql]   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

・経緯
最初にダウンロードした時に誤って2回ダウンロードをしていたようで、xamppとxampp1というファイルが存在していた。
検索したところ一度すべてアンストして再スタートするのが良い、とあったので実行。
しかし、全く同じエラーが表示されていいます。
xampp1のフォルダは既に削除済み（のはず）。

何度か似たような状況の質問も拝見いたしましたが、いかんせんまだリテラシーの低く、あまり技術力のない当方には理解できず、投稿させていただきました。

当方も検索や学習進めながら作業いたしますが、できるだけかみ砕いていただけますと大変ありがたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

--追記--
これはなんでしょう？
コマンドで操作するのだと思いますがその前後の作業が分からない、一度にどこまで打ち込めばいいのかもわからず、という状況です。
レジストリをいじるのは怖い、といろんな箇所に書いてあるので、怖くてまだ操作試していません。

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> services -> Apache2.4 ->ImagePath の値

値を"c:\xampp\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice に変更

Comment: 重複候補 - [XAMPP起動時にApache Service detected with wrong pathと表示される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31925/3060)

Comment: 解決しているので蛇足ですが、レジストリのパスを見て意味が分からないのならレジストリを触らない方がいいです。レジストリエディタは`Winキー`+Rで「ファイル名を指定して実行」を開き、`regedit`を入力後OKで開けます。ディレクトリのような構造になっているので、上記のHKEY〜も見ればわかると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます、参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アンインストーラーを利用して、一度すべてを削除し、再度ダウンロードして解決しました。

Comment: 削除しなければ、というのは分かっていたが、GUIでの右クリック→削除では完全に消せないということを分かっていなかった。アンインストーラーで正確に削除する手順が必要だった。